# How to find the Big-O of this function: $\ 2^{\log_2(n)^4} $

Tags: limits, asymptotics

The definition of Big-O is
$$u_n = O(v_n) \iff (\exists c \in \mathbb{R}^{*})\,\, (\exists N \in \mathbb{N}) \,\, n > N \implies u_n < c \, v_n$$

Based on that I am trying to find the upper bound for this function
$\ 2^{\log_2(n)^4} $, but I have no idea how to continue.

It seems legit to me though that $\ 2^{\log_2(n)^4} $ = O($\ 2^{\log(n)^4} $)

Is there a way to simplify this Big-O even more? E.g could we say that O($\ 2^{\log(n)^4} $) = O($\ 2^{\log(n)} $)

Comment: Your question is not well-defined. Since the function is in the Big-O of itself. So what exactly are you looking for? A 'simpler' function for the Big-O? Something else?

Comment: @AlexShtof Thank you for your observation. I edited my question. Yes, I am trying to find a way to simplify this even more, if thats possible. Could we say that O($\ 2^{log(n)^4} $) = O($\ 2^{log(n)} $)?

Comment: @Dimitris No, $2^{\log_2(n)}=n$, which grows much more slowly than $2^{\log_2(n)^4}$.

Comment: Thank you everybody.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What they probably mean is $\left(2^{\log_2 n}\right)^4$.  Because $2^{\log_2 n}=n$ this simplifies to $n^4$.  The conventional way to read $a^{b^c}$ is $a^{(b^c)}$, which in your case would mean the function is $2^{\left((\log_2 n)^4\right)}=n^{\left((\log_2 n)^3\right)}$  This grows faster than any polynomial.

Comment: It can be simplified to $n^{(\log n)^3}$, which makes it more obvious it grows faster than any polynomial.

Comment: @eyeballfrog:  good point